# Django app exited with code 252 on Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I am new to Docker, currently I am trying to deploy my app in a container. I have made 2 containers one for the DB and one for the app. But when I am trying to run my docker-compose file the app container exists with exit code 252. Here are the logs -

```
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  |
mushroomxpert_web_1 exited with code 252
```

This is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: mushroomxpert
    build: 
      context: ./web
    # command: 'gunicorn MushroomXpert.wsgi --log-file -'
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost
      - DEBUF=False
      - DB_NAME=mushroomxpert_db
      - DB_USER=mushroom_admin
      - DB_PASSWORD=chikchik1
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=chikchik1
      - POSTGRES_USER=mushroom_admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=mushroomxpert_db
```

EDIT 1- the problem seems to be occuring from Tensorflow, so I downgraded it's version to 2.2 after that the app worked. I am marking this as solved.

Comment: `DEBUF`? A typo?

Comment: Moreover, why did you add `image: mushroomxpert` ?

Comment: I renamed it to DEBUG, but still not working

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos for naming the container

Comment: Since you have both `image` and `build`, the part `build` will be ignored and only `image` will be executed. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Comment: There isn't any need for that, simply drop it and retry.

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos I removed the `image: mushroomxpert` part, but it's still giving the same exit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use something like this

```
version: "3.7"
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=chikchik1
      - POSTGRES_USER=mushroom_admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=mushroomxpert_db
    expose:
      - "5432"
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: YOUR DOCKERFILE
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "./backend/:/app/"
    environment:
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS: "localhost"
      - DEBUG: "False"
      - DB_NAME: "mushroomxpert_db"
      - DB_USER: "mushroom_admin"
      - DB_PASSWORD: "chikchik1"
      - DB_HOST: "db"
      - DB_PORT: "5432"
    env_file:
      - config.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: >-
      sh -c "
          pip install -r requirements.txt &&
          python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      "
```

The above configuration contains everything that you need and moreover the connection between the db and your django application.

Comment: I removed all my images and containers, but again when I try wiith this yaml file, it gives me the same exit code(252).

Comment: That's weird, give us more details about your local environment like os version etc. Did you try to use version 3 instead of version 3.7 ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I switched my PC os from Windows to Ubuntu and now my project exits with exit code 252 when runned locally. Is it possible that is something from the os?